# What is wrong with my X and Y coordinates in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, I have been having a go at canvas for the first time, I am trying to make a simple character walk around a room in which there are collidable objects, which are working. I was trying to write the logic of what should happen, if I stand within the object but it will move me to random places in the canvas.

Heres what I was trying to use:

```
if ((collisionPos[1] + collisionSize[1])  <= (player.pos[1] + player.sprite.size[1])) { 
    player.pos[1] = (collisionPos[1] + collisionSize[1]);
} else if ((player.pos[1] + player.sprite.size[1]) > collisionPos[1]) {
    player.pos[1] = (collisionPos[1] - player.sprite.size[1]);
}
if ((player.pos[0] + player.sprite.size[0]) >= (collisionPos[0] + collisionSize[0])) {
    player.pos[0] = (collisionPos[0] + collisionSize[0]);
} else if (collisionPos[0]  < (player.pos[0] + player.sprite.size[0])) {    
    Player.pos[0] = (collisionPos[0] - player.sprite.size[0]);
}
```

`collisionPos` is an array of the `x` and `y` of the collision position `(x, y)`, `collisionSize` is an array of the size of the object `(x, y)` and `player` is the player. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

If it helps collisions that exist are 
    {
                pos: [0, 0],
                size:[160, 48]
            },
            {
                pos: [160, 0],
                size:[200, 36]
            },
            {
                pos: [360, 0],
                size:[50, 400]
            },
            {
                pos: [240, 48],
                size:[50, 50]
            },
            {
                pos: [172, 120],
                size:[20, 60]
            }

and player.sprite.size = [32, 48]

Comment: I think this sort of question would really benefit from a working example.

Comment: Is the moving done using integers, or real numbers?

Comment: real numbers, the thing is if i take out one set it works fine for that direction, but if they're both in it just skips around

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this as a comment but it's too long so:

```
if ((collisionPos[1] + collisionSize[1])  <= (player.pos[1] + player.sprite.size[1])) { 
     // Collision bottom edge             <=    Player's bottom edge (<-- seems wrong I think no size should be inlcuded here.)
    player.pos[1] = (collisionPos[1] + collisionSize[1]);
    // player's top moves to botom edge of collision
} else if ((player.pos[1] + player.sprite.size[1]) > collisionPos[1]) {
    // player's bottom edge > collision top edge
    player.pos[1] = (collisionPos[1] - player.sprite.size[1]);
    // player's top moves to player's top edge minus player size 
}
if ((player.pos[0] + player.sprite.size[0]) >= (collisionPos[0] + collisionSize[0])) {
    // player's right edge                  >=  collision's right edge (<-- seems wrong I think no size should be inlcuded here.)
    player.pos[0] = (collisionPos[0] + collisionSize[0]);
    // player's left edge goes to collision's right edge
} else if (collisionPos[0]  < (player.pos[0] + player.sprite.size[0])) {    
    //  collision left edge <  player's right edge
    player.pos[0] = (collisionPos[0] - player.sprite.size[0]);
    // player's left edge moves to collision's left edge minus player's size
}
```

I think a few player's sprite sizes were added that might be causing some strange issues?

Also, more importantly, how do you do this check? Because if you're not careful implementing the check independently, the player could be beside a collision spot and still be 'above' it or below it. You should check x and y at the same time. Basically all your collision boxes could have infinite width/height this way. I think.